# Compare a value with the next in mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I have this documents on my database

`{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb579"} , "student_id" : 0 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 14.8504576811645}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57a"} , "student_id" : 0 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 63.98402553675503}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57d"} , "student_id" : 1 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 21.33260810416115}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57e"} , "student_id" : 1 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 44.31667452616328}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb581"} , "student_id" : 2 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 60.9750047106029}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb582"} , "student_id" : 2 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 97.75889721343528}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb585"} , "student_id" : 3 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 50.81577033538815}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb586"} , "student_id" : 3 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 92.71871597581605}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb589"} , "student_id" : 4 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 5.244452510818443}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb58a"} , "student_id" : 4 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 28.656451042441}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb58d"} , "student_id" : 5 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 23.29430953857654}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb58e"} , "student_id" : 5 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 41.21853026961924}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb591"} , "student_id" : 6 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 81.23822046161325}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb592"} , "student_id" : 6 , "type" : "homework" , "score" : 89.72700715074382}`

where `student_id` represents each student and each student made two homeworks worth a score of 100 in total, so, I want to compare both homeworks scores and delete the lower score of that student

here is my code so far

`try {
            Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost");

```
        DB db = mongo.getDB("students");   


        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("grades");  

        DBCursor cursor = collection.find();  
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();  
        query.put("type", "homework");  
        cursor = collection.find(query).sort(new BasicDBObject("student_id", 1));  
        System.out.println(cursor.count());  


        try{  
            while(cursor.hasNext()){  

                System.out.println(cursor.next());  

            }  
        }finally{  
            cursor.close();  
        }  

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {  

        e.printStackTrace();  
    }`
```

Comment: Wait, are you asking us to code a function to delete the lowest score of a student for you?

Comment: it dont need to be in code it can be in pseodocode or simple words just need a light @Sammaye

Comment: There are so many ways to do this, you could change your schema to embed homework scores in a student row or you could use the aggregation framework to $group: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#_S_group on student_id and use that as a basis you query for the homework scores of each student and use that, or you could do this client side in java by forming an array from your results of unique students and their scores and then delete the lowest score and then resave or whatever.

Comment: Thank you i had forgotten about aggregation i think this will help solve my problem